# Highcharts - dynamic flag color based on the value of the series

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to change the color of the flags based on the dynamic value of the dataseries its plotted against?

Comment: Yes, you can define color for each flag separately - see example http://jsfiddle.net/fj2qq5cm/

Comment: The value will be dynamic, how can i handle that?

Comment: Before you render the chart - process your data and set the color dynamically.